# Trouble deciphering Android stacktrace

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a live app and I am having some crashes that I cannot figure out.  When the app is installed for the first time it pulls down the database from my server and installs on the device.

I have not been able to duplicate this on my devices, so I am left with the stacktraces from the Android console.  I have the mappings files installed so it is de-obfuscated, but I just cannot figure out exactly where the problem is incurring.  It gives me a bunch of methods but I cannot tell which one is where the problem occurs.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique (code 19)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:971)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1484)
at com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit.database.ArmyProvider.bulkInsert(ArmyProvider.java)
at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.bulkInsert(ContentProvider.java:233)
at android.content.ContentResolver.bulkInsert(ContentResolver.java:1251)
at com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit.database.DataCreator.updateFullDbFromServer(DataCreator.java)
                                                      updateTableFromServer(DataCreator.java)
                                                      getValuesFromJsonObj(DataCreator.java)
                                                      addNewUser(DataCreator.java)
                                                      getGcmIdFromDb(DataCreator.java)
at com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit.database.DataCreator.updateFullDbFromServer(DataCreator.java)
                                                      updateTableFromServer(DataCreator.java)
                                                      getValuesFromJsonObj(DataCreator.java)
                                                      addNewUser(DataCreator.java)
                                                      getGcmIdFromDb(DataCreator.java)
at com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit.ui.MainBuilderActivity$1.onResponse(MainBuilderActivity.java)
at com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit.ui.MainBuilderActivity$1.onResponse(MainBuilderActivity.java)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java)
                                          parseNetworkResponse(JsonRequest.java)
at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

DataCreator.java

```
public class DataCreator {

//    private static final String TAG = DataCreator.class.getSimpleName();

public static void updateFullDbFromServer(JSONObject jsonObj, Context context) {
    Iterator<String> keys = jsonObj.keys();

    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String tableName = keys.next();
        try {
            updateTableFromServer(jsonObj.getJSONArray(tableName), context, tableName);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    setBaseTables(context);
}


private static void updateTableFromServer(JSONArray jsonArray, Context context, String tableName) {
    ContentValues[] valuesArray = new ContentValues[jsonArray.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            valuesArray[i] = getValuesFromJsonObj(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Uri uri = ArmyContract.BASE_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(tableName).build();
    context.getContentResolver().bulkInsert(uri, valuesArray);
}

private static ContentValues getValuesFromJsonObj(JSONObject jsonObj) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    try {
        Iterator<String> keys = jsonObj.keys();

        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            if (jsonObj.get(key) instanceof String) {
                values.put(key, jsonObj.getString(key));
            } else {
                values.put(key, jsonObj.getInt(key));
            }

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return values;
}

private static void setBaseTables(Context context) {
    ContentValues[] valuesArray = new ContentValues[6];

    valuesArray[0] = new ContentValues();
    valuesArray[0].put(ArmyContract.DisplayArmy.BARRACKS, 1);
    valuesArray[0].put(ArmyContract.DisplayArmy.OVERALL_TIME, "00:00:00");
    valuesArray[0].put(ArmyContract.DisplayArmy.TYPE, "elixer");
    valuesArray[1] = new ContentValues();
    valuesArray[1].put(ArmyContract.DisplayArmy.BARRACKS, 2);
    valuesArray[1].put(ArmyContract.DisplayArmy.OVERALL_TIME, "00:00:00");
    valuesArray[1].put(ArmyContract.DisplayArmy.TYPE, "elixer");
    valuesArray[2] = new ContentValues();
    valuesArray[2].put(ArmyContract.DisplayArmy.BARRACKS, 3);
    valuesArray[2].put(ArmyContract.DisplayArmy.OVERALL_TIME, "00:00:00");
    valuesArray[2].put(ArmyContract.DisplayArmy.TYPE, "elixer");
    valuesArray[3] = new ContentValues();
    valuesArray[3].put(ArmyContract.DisplayArmy.BARRACKS, 4);
    valuesArray[3].put(ArmyContract.DisplayArmy.OVERALL_TIME, "00:00:00");
    valuesArray[3].put(ArmyContract.DisplayArmy.TYPE, "elixer");
    valuesArray[4] = new ContentValues();
    valuesArray[4].put(ArmyContract.DisplayArmy.BARRACKS, 1);
    valuesArray[4].put(ArmyContract.DisplayArmy.OVERALL_TIME, "00:00:00");
    valuesArray[4].put(ArmyContract.DisplayArmy.TYPE, "dark");
    valuesArray[5] = new ContentValues();
    valuesArray[5].put(ArmyContract.DisplayArmy.BARRACKS, 2);
    valuesArray[5].put(ArmyContract.DisplayArmy.OVERALL_TIME, "00:00:00");
    valuesArray[5].put(ArmyContract.DisplayArmy.TYPE, "dark");

    //base row for the current army values table
    ContentValues currentArmyValues = new ContentValues();
    currentArmyValues.put(ArmyContract.CustomArmyValues.ARMY_NAME, "current");

    //base row for current army totals table
    ContentValues currentArmyTotals = new ContentValues();
    currentArmyTotals.put(ArmyContract.CurrentArmyTotals._ID, 1);

    context.getContentResolver().bulkInsert(ArmyContract.DisplayArmy.CONTENT_URI, valuesArray);
    context.getContentResolver().insert(ArmyContract.CustomArmyValues.CONTENT_URI, currentArmyValues);
    context.getContentResolver().insert(ArmyContract.CurrentArmyTotals.CONTENT_URI, currentArmyTotals);
}

public static void addNewUser(int userId, String token, Context context) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("main_id", userId);
    values.put("gcm_id", token);
    values.put("created_on", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()));

    context.getContentResolver().insert(Users.CONTENT_URI, values);
}

public static String getGcmIdFromDb(Context context) {
    String gcmId = "";
    String[] columns = {"gcm_id"};
    String whereClause = "_id=?";
    String[] args = {"1"};

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Users.CONTENT_URI, columns, whereClause, args, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        gcmId = cursor.getString(0);
        cursor.close();
        return gcmId;
    } else {
        return gcmId;
    }
}


}
```

DBHelper.java

```
 final String SQL_CREATE_USERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Users.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            Users._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            Users.MAIN_ID + " INTEGER, " +
            Users.GCM_ID + " INTEGER, " +
            Users.WEB_KEY + " TEXT, " +
            Users.NICKNAME + " TEXT," +
            Users.EMAIL + " TEXT," +
            Users.CREATED_ON + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            Users.CLAN_ID + " INTEGER, " +
            Users.CLAN_POSITION + " INTEGER " +
            ");";

    final String SQL_CREATE_CUSTOM_ARMY_VALUES = " CREATE TABLE " + CustomArmyValues.CUSTOM_ARMY_VALUES + " (" +
            CustomArmyValues._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            CustomArmyValues.ARMY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            CustomArmyValues.USER_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            CustomArmyValues.BARBARIAN + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.ARCHER + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.GIANT + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.GOBLIN + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.WALL_BREAKER + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.BALLOON + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.WIZARD + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.HEALER + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.DRAGON + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.PEKKA + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.MINION + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.HOG_RIDER + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.VALKYRIE + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.GOLEM + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.WITCH + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.LAVA_HOUND + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.BOWLER + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.BABY_DRAGON + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.MINER + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.LIGHTNING + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.HEAL + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.RAGE + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.JUMP + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.FREEZE + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.CLONE + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.POISON + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.EARTHQUAKE + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.HASTE + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.SKELETON + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.TOWN_HALL_REQ + " INTEGER, " +
            CustomArmyValues.ARMY_TYPE + " TEXT, " +
            CustomArmyValues.UPDATED + " TEXT " +
            ");";
    final String SQL_CREATE_CURRENT_ARMY_TOTALS = " CREATE TABLE " + CurrentArmyTotals.CURRENT_ARMY_TOTALS + " (" +
            CurrentArmyTotals._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            CurrentArmyTotals.ELIXER_TROOP_COST + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            CurrentArmyTotals.ELIXER_SPELL_COST + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            CurrentArmyTotals.DE_TROOP_COST + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            CurrentArmyTotals.DE_SPELL_COST + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            CurrentArmyTotals.ELIXER_TOTAL_TIME + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            CurrentArmyTotals.DE_TOTAL_TIME + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            CurrentArmyTotals.SPELL_TOTAL_TIME + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            CurrentArmyTotals.HERO_TIME + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            CurrentArmyTotals.ELIXER_TROOP_COUNT + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            CurrentArmyTotals.DARK_TROOP_COUNT + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            CurrentArmyTotals.SPELL_COUNT + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            CurrentArmyTotals.CAMP_CAPACITY + " INTEGER DEFAULT 240, " +
            CurrentArmyTotals.FACTORY_CAPACITY + " INTEGER DEFAULT 11 " +
            ");";

    final String SQL_CREATE_HERO_LEVEL = " CREATE TABLE " + ArmyContract.HeroLevel.HERO_LEVEL + " (" +
            HeroLevel._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            HeroLevel.NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            HeroLevel.LEVEL + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            HeroLevel.REGEN_TIME + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            HeroLevel.UPDATED + " TEXT NOT NULL " +
            ");";
    final String SQL_CREATE_DISPLAY_ARMY = " CREATE TABLE " + DisplayArmy.DISPLAY_ARMY + " (" +
            DisplayArmy._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            DisplayArmy.BARRACKS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            DisplayArmy.TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            DisplayArmy.BARBARIAN + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            DisplayArmy.ARCHER + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            DisplayArmy.GIANT + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            DisplayArmy.GOBLIN + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            DisplayArmy.WALL_BREAKER + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            DisplayArmy.BALLOON + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            DisplayArmy.WIZARD + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            DisplayArmy.HEALER + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            DisplayArmy.DRAGON + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            DisplayArmy.PEKKA + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            DisplayArmy.BABY_DRAGON + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            DisplayArmy.MINER + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            DisplayArmy.MINION + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            DisplayArmy.HOG_RIDER + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            DisplayArmy.VALKYRIE + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            DisplayArmy.GOLEM + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            DisplayArmy.WITCH + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            DisplayArmy.LAVA_HOUND + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            DisplayArmy.BOWLER + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
            DisplayArmy.OVERALL_TIME + " TEXT " +
            " );";
    final String SQL_CREATE_BUILDABLE = " CREATE TABLE " + Buildable.BUILDABLE + " (" +
            Buildable._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            Buildable.NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            Buildable.BUILD_TIME + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            Buildable.BUILDER_SPACE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            Buildable.BUILDER_REQ + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            Buildable.CURRENT_LEVEL + " INTEGER DEFAULT 1, " +
            Buildable.LEVEL_COUNT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            Buildable.ELIXER_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            Buildable.BUILDABLE_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            Buildable.UPDATED + " TEXT NOT NULL " +
            " );";
    final String SQL_CREATE_BUILDABLE_LEVEL = " CREATE TABLE " + BuildableLevel.BUILDABLE_LEVEL + " (" +
            BuildableLevel._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            BuildableLevel.LEVEL + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            BuildableLevel.BUILDABLE_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            BuildableLevel.BUILD_COST + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            BuildableLevel.UPDATED + " TEXT NOT NULL " +
            " );";
    final String SQL_CREATE_BUILDER = " CREATE TABLE " + Builder.BUILDER + " (" +
            Builder._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            Builder.CURRENT_LEVEL + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, " +
            Builder.CURRENT_BOOST + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, " +
            Builder.BUILDER_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            Builder.ELIXER_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            Builder.LEVEL_COUNT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            Builder.UPDATED + " TEXT NOT NULL " +
            " );";
    final String SQL_CREATE_BUILDER_LEVEL = " CREATE TABLE " + ArmyContract.BuilderLevel.BUILDER_LEVEL + " (" +
            BuilderLevel._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            BuilderLevel.LEVEL + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0," +
            BuilderLevel.CAPACITY + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            BuilderLevel.BUILDER_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            BuilderLevel.ELIXER_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            BuilderLevel.UPDATED + " TEXT NOT NULL " +
            " );";
    final String SQL_CREATE_CONTAINER = " CREATE TABLE " + Container.CONTAINER + " (" +
            Container._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            Container.CURRENT_LEVEL + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, " +
            Container.LEVEL_COUNT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            Container.ARMY_OBJ_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            Container.UPDATED + " TEXT NOT NULL " +
            " );";
    final String SQL_CREATE_CONTAINER_LEVEL = " CREATE TABLE " + ContainerLevel.CONTAINER_LEVEL + " (" +
            ContainerLevel._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            ContainerLevel.LEVEL + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            ContainerLevel.CAPACITY + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            ContainerLevel.ARMY_OBJ_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            ContainerLevel.UPDATED + " TEXT NOT NULL " +
            " );";
    final String SQL_CREATE_HEROES = " CREATE TABLE " + ArmyContract.Heroes.HEROES + " (" +
            ArmyContract.Heroes._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            ArmyContract.Heroes.CURRENT_LEVEL + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, " +
            ArmyContract.Heroes.CURRENT_BOOST + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            ArmyContract.Heroes.NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            ArmyContract.Heroes.LEVEL_COUNT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            ArmyContract.Heroes.UPDATED + " TEXT NOT NULL " +
            " );";

    final String SQL_CREATE_LIKED = " CREATE TABLE " + ArmyContract.LikedArmies.LIKED_ARMIES + " (" +
            ArmyContract.LikedArmies._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            ArmyContract.LikedArmies.ARMY_ID + " INTEGER " +
            " );";

    final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_VERSION = " CREATE TABLE " + ArmyContract.TableVersion.TABLE_VERSION + " (" +
            ArmyContract.TableVersion._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            ArmyContract.TableVersion.TABLE_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            ArmyContract.TableVersion.VERSION + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            ArmyContract.TableVersion.UPDATED + " TEXT NOT NULL " +
            " );";
```

Comment: Judging from the first line only, you're trying to insert a non-unique primary key into the database. Can you share some code?

Comment: The question is, where is it trying to insert a non-unique primary key.  I don't have anything that should up inserting primary keys.  I will include the `DataCreator` class.  Let me know if you need to see something else. It's only happening on a small percentage of installs as well, which is odd

Comment: What is the schema for this table?

Comment: There are multiple tables.  I will upload the dbhelper class